# Displaying feedburner media enclosure to tableview

Tags: ios, rss, feedburner

I am working with

```
 https://github.com/tiboll/BlockRSSParser
```

to get RSS data and showing in a tableview , everything works fine but , this project does not display images correctly ! , so I find :

```
 http://feedburner.google.com/
```

and  create my RSS feed with this site , now every thing works fine except something ! some web site like :

```
http://feeds.gawker.com/lifehacker/full
```

it has images which we can see on RSS feed so I am able to display them in my tableview :
[image]

but for some rss feeds , feedburner gives me MEDIA ENCLOSURE , that rss can not get its image and display them into tableview's cell :

[image]

how can I convert this image's url to show image file for cell.imageView?

CODE :

```
if ([[item imagesFromItemDescription] count]>0) {
        [cell.thumbnail setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[item.imagesFromItemDescription objectAtIndex:0]]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this tutorial for RSS data Read

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial

use this method

```
  - (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries 
      NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
      for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {
           NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
           for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {
           }
       }
    }
```

fetch one by one tag and reach to image tag....

Comment: thanks but I don't want to change my methods by the way this tutorial does not show any image data